# Executing xsdata [CLI] for multiple JSON to create a model

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, xml, model

Here I am trying to generate a model.py file having class Model using XSDATA[CLI].
I am able to create the Model class as well as the directory using the following command

```
xsdata file_name.json --output dataclasses --package models
```

But I have multiple json which I require under the same Model class, but if I execute the above command separately for each file the Model class will have the last executed command under Model.

To execute all the JSON togethers, I have tried these commands already:

```
xsdata file1.json file2.json file3.json file4.json --output dataclasses --package models
```

```
xsdata input/*.json --output dataclasses --package models
```

```
xsdata "input/*.json" --output dataclasses --package models`
```

```
xsdata input/\*.json --output dataclasses --package models
```

But all of them return `Error: Got unexpected extra arguments`

How can I execute all the json stored inside input directory to create a Model class with all require parameters under it rather than the latest parameter only?

Comment: It looks like xsdata can scan a directory for multiple input files. See https://xsdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/codegen.html#id1

Comment: Hi @mzjn: That worked, I was trying input/*.json to read all json files but if we just pass input/ it will read all together and generate model class.

Comment: '''
xsdata input/ --output dataclasses --packages models
'''
This worked well, just by passing input  or input/*.json was giving error